# Finding, which web component is causing problems during page loading

Tags: firefox

I am using windows version of Firefox 5.0 and last few days I found that on one [website](http://www.zive.cz/Poradna/) (similar focus as stackexchange but in Czech), is something wrong as my browser loads it very slowly (while the connection is ok and never had problems with it). There is also another guy trying to solve the almost the same problem, but no help yet.

So I would ask, whether there is some Firefox plugin showing which page components are loading and which could help me to find out the problem. I am writing from office pc so we have blocked all the social networks like FB, Twitter etc. and I also use Adblock Plus - however, deactivating it does not have any effect on it.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

You can use it to do a hell of a lot but you might be most interested in [profiling the network activity](http://getfirebug.com/network) or [javascript](http://getfirebug.com/javascript).